# how (where) to define a feature step in Behat/Mink

Tags: yii, bdd, behat, mink

I'm experiencing problems with defining my own steps for BDD features in Behat and Mink setup in Yii framework.

I've successefully installed Behat with Mink extension following the instructions from [MinkExtension-example](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension-example/blob/master/README.md).

After all that, I have the following structure of my folders inside **myapp/private_html/** (some deeply nested folders were omitted):

```
├───bin
├───commands
│   └───shell
├───components
├───config
├───controllers
├───features
│   ├───bootstrap
│   └───php54_bootstrap
├───models
├───tests
├───vendor
│   ├───behat
│   │   ├───behat
│   │   │   ├───bin
│   │   │   ├───features
│   │   │   │   ├───annotations
│   │   │   │   ├───bootstrap
│   │   │   │   └───closures
└───views
```

A feature provided as an example in the above mentioned link [MinkExtension-example](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension-example/blob/master/README.md) works without a problem. But when I define my own step like

```
  Scenario: presence of menu items
    Given I am on "/"
    Then I should see the following: "Home, About, Contact"
```

I get

```
1 scenario (1 undefined)
2 steps (1 passed, 1 undefined)
0m2.288s
```

with a suggestion

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

/**
 * @Then /^I should see the following: "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iShouldSeeTheFollowing($arg1)
{
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

And the question is: where should I put this code? I've tried to put it in

```
myapp\private_html\features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php
```

as well as in

```
myapp\private_html\vendor\behat\behat\features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php
```

but the step remains undefined.

So, where are the steps supposed to be defined?

Answer (score 1):

You never have to change vendor's code (I suppose you are using composer). Is not your code.

You code must to be added to features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php.

Maybe the problem is that your FeatureContext class dont extends MinkContext but BehatContext. Y'll find a comment in FeatureContext's file. Change parent class of FeatureContext from BehatContext to MinkContext.

Finally, to see all sentences that your context can see, run "./bin/behat -dl". If you run this command before change Context, you can see that behat has few sentences.

Comment: You say that those two folders **vendor** and **bin** are public despite the fact they are in the **private_html** folder? I'll try with you suggestions about adding step definitions to the file **features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php**.

Comment: No sorry. I've delete that part of answer.

Comment: I tried to add my steps to **features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php** and as before, the step remains undefined. Indeed, I do not understand the idea of the context that you mentioned, but I tried to do something:
1. first try was to add **$this->useContext('mink', new MinkContext());** into the constructor - but nothing changed
2. then I added **use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;** - and again nothing changed.
BTW what do you mean saying **Change parent folder of FeatureContext from BehatContext to MinkContext**?

Comment: And naturally, the step is not displayed when I run **./bin/behat -dl**

Comment: Sorry: I mean, ... parent class.

Comment: I followed instructions on the official [Behat site](http://docs.behat.org/quick_intro.html#installation) and now I can add steps in FeatureContext.php and they appear when I run `behat --init`.  The problem is that there are no predefined steps...

Comment: I've found out what was the problem. The example I've taken is based on [this behat configuration file](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension-example/blob/master/behat.yml.dist) that somehow overrides the default context in such a way that whatever steps I add to my `bootstrap/FeatureContext.php` it gets just ignored. In the absence of `behat.yml` file, I can see the steps in my `FeatureContext`.

Comment: I would say that now it sees the steps I add into FeatureContext.

Comment: The future context you modify is /feature/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php or /vendor/behat/behat/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php?

Comment: As you properly suggested, I modify only **/feature/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php**.

Comment: I put it [here](http://pastebin.com/n1P8KxBk) thought it is just a copy-paste version of behat.yml.dist of the [example](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension-example/blob/master/README.md) that I considered.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to see the predefined steps and functions by behat mink.

```
vendor/bin/behat -dl
```

you will see the steps u can use for ur site.

Now theres already a step you can use

```
Scenario: presence of menu items
 Given I am on "/"
 Then I should see "Home, About, Contact"
 Theres nothing like "Then I should see following".
```

Comment: You are absolutely right that **Then I should see following** is not among predefined steps. This was exactly the reason I wanted to define it in my FeatureContext file.

Comment: copy all of the given snippet including the comments under your features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php file. are you copying everything ?

Comment: exactly, I've copied everything. The step remained undefined. As I suppose this is due to the settings in the behat.yml file that I used from the example.

Comment: hmm i think the commas inside the   "Home, About, Contact" may not be working. coz if you focus on the function its passing only a single argument($arg1). so definitely it has to be with the arguments you are declaring. you want 3 things to be found on the page : Home,About,Contact . but the function only passes a single argument. got that ??

Comment: It was obvious from the very begining and namely this fact was the reason of creating a new step that I called `Then I should see the following: "....."`. And the problem was that this step remained undefined even if I explicitely define it in the FeatureContext. Sorry if I was not clear when posting the question.